# How can I make my 'sunspot-solr start' work?

Tags: solr, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I'm have problem to start my sunspot-solr.
I'm fallowing instructions from this [github/wiki](http://wiki.github.com/outoftime/sunspot/sunspot-and-rails-3-with-websolr)

So I made the installation part without trouble apparently.
End then I tried to start it with:

```
sunspot-solr start -p 8982 -d solr/data/development -s solr --pid-dir=tmp/pids -l FINE --log-file=log/sunspot-solr-development.log
```

It didn't show me any error, but I can't access to 'http://localhost:8982/solr/admin'. 
More strange, in Myapp/log/, I don't have any sunspot-solr-development.log

I'm on ubuntu, and I need help.

thanks.

ps: if someone knows how to run some things like 'rake sunspot:reindex' but for the rails 3 versions, it will be great

Answer (score 1):

Ok never mind, I find what's wrong.

It was not a big deal, I just forget that solr work with java.

So for those who work on Ubuntu, don't forget the :

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```